# Magento 2 - How to trigger Customer Segment Data Refresh?

Tags: magento2, magento-2-commerce, customer-segmentation

After migration from Magento1 Enterprise to Magento2 Commerce I need to programmatically refresh the customer segments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this method to be used by our post migration command:

```
public function refreshSegments()
{
    $segments = $this->customerSegmentCollection->create();
    /** @var \Magento\CustomerSegment\Model\Segment $segment */
    foreach ($segments as $segment) {
        echo "Updating: ".$segment->getName()."\r\n";
        $segment->matchCustomers();
    }
}
```